# Can I use Amazon SES and S3 with ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ses

Simple question:

Can I use Amazon Simple Email Service with my ECS containers? I'm using the Fargate launch type with ECS.
What about S3?

Basically my question is, can I use any amazon service (assuming it's available in my region)? So is everything I could use with EC2 also supported by ECS or are there limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. There's no limitation preventing you from making network calls from ECS containers to any other AWS service.

Answer (score 0):

IF you provide proper authorization via roles you can do anything.

Copying a paragraph for your reference from aws docs :

"The task execution role grants the Amazon ECS container and Fargate agents permission to make AWS API calls on your behalf. The task execution IAM role is required depending on the requirements of your task. You can have multiple task execution roles for different purposes and services associated with your account"

Please refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task_execution_IAM_role.htmlhttps://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html